# Android Updating OpenGL onclick

Tags: android, opengl-es, onclick

i have a GLSurfaceView, that has a texture that i need to change when i click on a button.
How can i do this on android.
I managed something with:

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

But i need to refresh only openGL and not the whole program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is **NOT** the way to refresh your view. you need to use the `invalidate` function.

for more:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing
2. [android on openGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).
3. [openGL tutorial number 1](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html).
4. [openGL tutorial number 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB2gquFQ3Cc).

Comment: ok only invalidate? or do i have to validate it after? I tried this code but it doesn't work:
 public void onClick(View v) {
             View mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1); 
             if (Square.getSex()==2130837504){
              Square.setSex(2130837505);
             }
             else
              Square.setSex(2130837504);
             
             mGLView.invalidate();
            }

Also i guess i have to validate the SurfaceView, Corect?

Comment: invalidate, causes the View to be re drawn. no need to validate. try reading more in the link I gave you. I also will update my answer shortly with links to more tuts on that

Comment: 10x a lot, i managed with invalidate :D and now I'm looking over the tutorials, great stuff